# Функция для удаления определенного символа в Python

Tags: python

Друзья, добрый день!
Мне нужно реализовать функцию. Она принимает на вход строку и символ и возвращает новую строку, в которой удалён переданный символ во всех его позициях.
Мой код:

```
def filter_string(text, char):
    result = ''
    for current_char in text:
        if current_char.upper() != char.upper():
            result += current_char
    return result
```

Но к сожалению, он работает некорректно.
Ожидается:

```
filter_string(text, 'i')  # 'f  look forward  wn'
filter_string(text, 'O')  # 'If I lk frward I win
```

Ошибка:

```
def test():
       text = 'I look back if you are lost'
       assert filter_string(text, 'w') == 'I look back if you are lost'       AssertionError: assert 'I' == 'I look back if you are lost'
        - I look back if you are lost
        + I

tests/test_solution.py:6: AssertionError
short test summary info 
FAILED tests/test_solution.py::test - AssertionError: assert 'I' == 'I look b...
```

Спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Исключение срабатывает? У вас отступы некорректные. А сама функция рабочая, хоть и не оптимальная.

Comment: Да, все работает, вроде, если отступы исправить. "Некорректно" = плохо скопировали чужую функцию и на синтаксис Python ругается? Приводите конкретные тестовые примеры, пожалуйста. Что на входе, что ожидается на выходе, что на самом деле на выходе. Текст ошибки, если есть, и указание на строку к которой она выдана. Тогда выше шанс получить помощь.

Comment: Вы удаляете символ вне зависимости от регистра, или требуется полное соответствие?

Comment: Регистр не имеет значения.

Comment: у вас  return внутри блока  if  и на первом же шаге цикла возвращает результат.
проблема все таки с отступами

Comment: исправил, не помогает(

Comment: Ошибка все та же? `AssertionError: assert 'I' == 'I look back if you are lost' `?

Comment: Да, ошибка та же

Comment: @LevinAlex Может вы в изначальном вопросе всё же приведете отступы в порядок? Это поможет понять что у вас там.

Comment: Там написаны тесты? раз выпадает AssertionError...

Comment: @Alpensin я исправил отступы

Comment: @DaniilLoban да, тесты есть, учебная задачка

Comment: @LevinAlex В коде в вопросе этого не видно. Содержимое функции на уровне объявления функции. return внутри блока if.

Comment: @Alpensin переделал правку

Comment: покажите функции тестов, их может быть несколько

Comment: @DaniilLoban                                                                                                                                     from solution import filter_string


def test():
    text = 'I look back if you are lost'
    assert filter_string(text, 'w') == 'I look back if you are lost'
    assert filter_string(text, 'I') == 'look back f you are lost'
    assert filter_string(text, 'o') == 'I lk back if yu are lst'
    assert filter_string('zz zorro', 'z') == 'orro'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для начала покажу фикс на который многие и без меня указывали в комментариях

```
def filter_string(text, char):
    result = ''
    for current_char in text:
        print(current_char)
        if current_char.upper() != char.upper():
            result += current_char
    return result
```

Если задача не учебная, и даже если она учебная то тем более хорошо знать строковые функции присутсвующие в языке. Эту задачу можно реализовать например строковой функцией replace()

**Параметры**

- old – это старая подстрока, которая будет заменена.
- new – это новая подстрока, которая заменит старую подстроку.
- max – это дополнительный аргумент, заменяется только первые max вхождений.

**Возвращаемое значение**

Эта функция возвращает копию строки со всеми вхождениями старой подстроки заменен новой. Если указывается дополнительный аргумент max, только заменяются только первые max вхождений.
Пример

Следующий пример показывает использование функции replace().

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

str = "это пример строки....wow!!! это действительно строка"
print (str.replace("wow", "поразительно"))
print (str.replace("это", "здесь", 3))
```

Результат выведет 2 строки

```
это пример строки....поразительно!!! это действительно строка
здесь пример строки....wow!!! здесь действительно строка
```

Пример как использовать реплейс как удаление:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я знаком с replace. Для решения этой задачи она не подходит.

Comment: замена должна быть на пустой символ `""` - это и есть удаление

Comment: не совсем понял как в этой задаче можно использовать replace?

Comment: дополнил примером с удалением

Comment: кстати чтобы регистр действительно не имел значения то можно использовать функцию `re.sub` которая находится в модуле `re` пример можно глянуть [тут](https://pythonz.net/references/named/re.sub/)

Comment: Ошибка из-за пробела в начале строки. Не знаю как ее убрать

Comment: Убрал при помощи lstrip(). Спасибо за помощь!!!

Comment: Не стоило убирать ошибка в самом тесте, пробел должен быть потому что он есть `I look`

Comment: Проверку задача прошла на сайте)

Comment: Если есть возможность связаться с разработчиками теста то можно написать чтобы пофиксили)

Answer (score 0):

```
filter_string = lambda t, c: t.translate({ord(c): '', ord(c.swapcase()): ''})
filter_string('f lOok forward wn', 'o')  # 'f lk frward wn'
```

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант:

```py
def filter_string(text, char):
    return ''.join(filter(lambda x: x.upper() != char.upper(), text))

text = 'I look back if you are lost'
print(filter_string(text, 'i'))
#  look back f you are lost
```

Answer (score 0):

знакомое задание, ты забыл обозначить, что "Итоговая строка также не должна содержать начальные и концевые пробелы"

return result.strip() и всё заработает

Comment: Непохоже, чтобы проблема автора вопроса была связана с удалением пробелов.